# Repeated Class with Different CSS Widths

Tags: html, css

I've a CSS class which I want to repeat with different widths defined each time. The page displays performance in different categories. The problem, of course, is that at every occasion the class appears, the final CSS declared styles all of the class elements. How can I make it so each row has different widths with the same class? Is it possible with CSS? Ideally I don't want to have to use JS.

Code below-

```
<style type="text/css">.resultsbar > div {width: 23%;} .altresults {margin-left: calc(23% + 10px);}</style>
<div class="resultsbar">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 23%; margin-left: calc(23% + 10px);">
    <div class="fr">DONE: 23%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="altresults">TO DO: 77%</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">.resultsbar > div {width: 43%;} .altresults {margin-left: calc(43% + 10px);}</style>
<div class="resultsbar">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 43%; margin-left: calc(43% + 10px);">
    <div class="fr">DONE: 43%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="altresults">TO DO: 57%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't, CSS can't detect what text is in an element....sounds like you need Javascript.

Comment: If the class is to remain constant you need some other method of applying the widths. Since this will involve either additional selectors (which apparently will not be known) or **inline styles**, JS would seem to be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

yes i guess we can do that by using (:nth-of-type(1)...(2)....(3) whatever).
    you can just assign the perticular differnt width to that box or div as i added example:

```
.resultsbar:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 53%;
}
like that. :)
```

Answer (score 0):

use css "nth-child" property to possible not require js

example

```css
.resultsbar{
 float:left;
width:100%;
}
.resultsbar .bar {
width:23%;
 float:left;
}
.resultsbar .altresults {
width:77%;
 float:left;
}
.resultsbar:nth-child(2n) .bar {
width:43%;
 float:left;
}
.resultsbar:nth-child(2n) .altresults {
width:57%;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="resultsbar">
<div class="bar">
<div class="fr">DONE: 27%</div>
</div>
<div class="altresults">TO DO: 77%</div>
</div>

<div class="resultsbar">
<div class="bar">
<div class="fr">DONE: 43%</div>
</div>
<div class="altresults">TO DO: 57%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of including `<style>...</style>` tag and updating it by class name, insted you can add `inline style` as shown below

```
<div class="resultsbar">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 23%; margin-left: calc(23% + 10px);">
    <div class="fr">DONE: 23%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="altresults">TO DO: 77%</div>
</div>
<div class="resultsbar">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 43%; margin-left: calc(43% + 10px);">
    <div class="fr">DONE: 43%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="altresults">TO DO: 57%</div>
</div>
```